# 404 every page except index.php

Tags: error, 404

I check some answers here but no one seems to work properly in my case.

I have an magento 2.3 store, that works well in my localhost windows.
When I send to my host site every page except `index.php` give me **whoops 404**.

This commands won't work properly:

> - php bin/magento setup:upgrade
> - php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
> - php bin/magento cache:clean

If I use `mysite.com.br/index.php/otherpage.html` it works.

Have some way to chance all the URL to remove `index.php` from them?

Comment: ok I have answer

Comment: If the server is using APACHE, then the first thing to check is **`mod_rewrite`** should be enabled.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora Yes mod_rewrite is enabled.

Comment: @sarveshDineshkumarPatel - Can you please specify which lines do I need to change? And as I said in other answer, I`m not abble to reach at admin painel :/

Comment: ok so share me your store url please

Answer (score 0):

Please try below steps.

```
1. Log in to Admin Panel
2. Navigate to System > Configuration > General > Web
3. Expand the Search Engines Optimization section
4. Set “yes” to Use Web Server Rewrites option.
5. Expand the Secure tab
6. Set “yes” to Use Secure URLs in Frontend

===>>
In .htaccess file on root
If your Magento store is installed in root (mainroot), use this:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

If your Magento store is installed in a subfolder (mainroot/subfolder), use this:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /shop/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /shop/index.php [L]
```

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, I`ll try the steps bellow and tell if works.

I forgot to mention, I`m not able to access the Admin painel don`t know why, when I try to access got the 404 error.

Even with mysite.com.br/index.php/admin wont work.

Thanks again.

This is my .htaccess which lines do I have to change?

#

### Optional override of deployment mode. We recommend you use the

### command bin/magento deploy:mode:set to switch modes instead

## Options are default, production, or developer

## SetEnv MAGE_MODE default

#

### Uncomment these lines for CGI mode.

### Make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name

### it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

## Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi

## AddHandler php5-cgi .php

#

### GoDaddy specific options

## Options -MultiViews

### You might also need to add this line to php.ini

### cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1

### If it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

#

### This line is specific for 1and1 hosting

```
#AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
#AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
```

#

### Default index file

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

#

### Adjust memory limit

```
php_value memory_limit 756000M
php_value max_execution_time 18000000
```

#

### Disable automatic session start

### before autoload was initialized

```
php_flag session.auto_start off
```

#

## Disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

```
php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
```

#

### Adjust memory limit

```
php_value memory_limit 756000M
php_value max_execution_time 18000000
```

#

### Disable automatic session start

### before autoload was initialized

```
php_flag session.auto_start off
```

#

### Enable resulting html compression

```
#php_flag zlib.output_compression on
```

#

## Disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

```
php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
```

#

## Disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

```
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
```

#

### Enable apache served files compression

### http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

```
# Insert filter on all content
###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Insert filter on selected content types only
#AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

# Netscape 4.x has some problems...
#BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
#BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
#BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Don't compress images
#SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
#Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
```

#

### Make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

```
SSLOptions StdEnvVars
```

#

### Enable rewrites

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
Options -MultiViews
```

#

### You can put here your magento root folder

### path relative to web root

```
#RewriteBase /magento/
```

#

### Workaround for HTTP authorization

### in CGI environment

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

#

### TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
```

#

### Never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

#

### Rewrite everything else to index.php

```
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

#

### Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides

### If you still have problems, use the second line instead

```
AddDefaultCharset Off
#AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

#

### Add default Expires header

### http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

```
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/html A0
ExpiresByType text/plain A0
```

#

### Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

```
<Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
```

## For 404s and 403s that aren't handled by the application, show plain 404 response

ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.php
ErrorDocument 403 /errors/404.php

#

### If running in cluster environment, uncomment this

### http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

```
#FileETag none
```

#

### Deny access  to cron.php

```
<Files cron.php>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
```

### Deny access  to .user.ini

```
<Files .user.ini>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
        Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
</Files>
```

############################################
    ## Prevent clickjacking
    Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN